# mediaplayer one sound at time

Tags: android, audio

i'm newbie in this world of programming, i want reproduce one sound at time, is a application with long sounds of animals.

when i push some button make sound about some animals (gato make sound of a cat)
i fail to play a sound at time, i try with soundpool too, same results, obviously the problem are my low lvl of programming xD, can somebody help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void presionGato(View v) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.create(this, R.raw.gato);
    mp.start();
}
public void presionLeon(View v) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.create(this, R.raw.leon);
    mp.start();
    }
public void presionPerro(View v) {
    mp.stop();
    mp = mp.create (this, R.raw.perro);
    mp.start();
}
public void presionTigre(View v) {
    mp = mp.create (this, R.raw.tigre);
    mp.start();
}
public void presionRata(View v) {
    mp = mp.create (this, R.raw.rata);
    mp.start();

}
public void presionSapo(View v) {
    mp = mp.create (this, R.raw.sapo);
    mp.start();
}
public void presionRana(View v) {
    mp = mp.create (this, R.raw.rana);
    mp.start();
}

}
```

Comment: So when you press on gato and then press on leon, gato and leon is playing at the same time?

Comment: Yes, now, with that code, nothing happen, the application clash :), but when i press rata and sapo, both sound is playing at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to you, learn programming and search about it. You didn't listen anything from UI, how can you know which button was clicked?

first, initialize UI element and media player on onCreate;

```
Button gatoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gato);
Button leonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.leon);
mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

then set onClickListener for each button.

```
gatoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                presionGato();
            }});

leonButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                presionLeon();
            }});
```

Comment: Thanks! is there any way to start a sound when you open the application?

Comment: Yes, you can call function of the play sound (what you want) in onCreate. But you should decide when sound will stop playing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`if(mp.isPlaying()){
mp.stop();
mp.release();
}`

it will stop the music if it is playing then you can start the your new music again. It prevent to play the music at the same time.